# Geospatial filtering of documents with locations within a given radius from given point with LoopbackJS

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

There is a requirement to do a query for documents which are within a certain radius from a given point. If you use MongoDB as a database, you can do the following:

- create geospatial 2dsphere index;
- save data in a proper format;
- filter documents which are within distance of 10 miles from given location you would do: `db.Location.find({loc: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[-110.111111, 30.333333], 10 / 3963.2]}}})`

What would be the proper way to achieve the same using Loopback's `Geopoint`, `near` and `lt`?

Crossposted here as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/ncG7NdJ-eEQ

Answer (score 1):

**Location.find({where: {loc: {near: [-110.111111, 30.333333], maxDistance: 10}}})**

This will do where 'Location' is your model name. 'loc' is your location field.
'near' specifies center coordinates. and 'maxDistance' specifies area to cover.

Also, this is for 2d indexes.

Comment: Does this order by distance?

Comment: I have tried it yet, but you can alter the above query with the help of this article: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Order-filter.html